# Implementing undo in Java for state changes

Tags: java, design-patterns, undo-redo

I am starting to implementing the command pattern in the hope to get a useful solution to my problem of providing an undo operation. Now I am facing a certain issue:

Implementing undo when operations are involved are rather easy: when I've added 5 to a number then I subtract 5. When I've added an object to a list, then I remove it, and so on. But what if I have a total state and not something like a list?

An example: I model information about a thread in a class:

```
public class ThreadInfo implements Comparable<ThreadInfo> {

    final int id;
    String name;
    int priority;
    String state;
    int waitCount;
    // ...
}
```

Certain information does not change, for instance the id. Undoing the `waitCount` is easy as described above, just subtract. But what about `priority` or `state`? It is not clear how to undo these information.

The only idea I came up with: when initializing the command object, preserve the old state in it's object: by passing the relevant data into the constructor:

```
public MyCommand(int priority, String state) {
   previousPriority = priority;
   previousState = state;
}
```

Or would it be better to let `ThreadInfo` have a list of states and priorities with being the first elements the current?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just hold old state in command. for example

```
 class ChangeFoo {
    ChangeFoo (Bar bar, foo newFoo){}
    void execute(){
        oldFoo = bar.getFoo();
        bar.setFoo(newFoo);
    }
    void undo(){
        bar.setFoo(oldFoo);
    }
 }
```

Comment: Or hold a Collection<T> of them on a stack.

Comment: @Hovercraft That was the second approach I was thinking of!

Comment: @platzhirsch: It all depends on how many levels of undo you desire.

Comment: @Hovercraft: Well, I have something about 20.000 to 100.000 undo. But why does it matter?

Answer (score 2):

I would go for the first solution: MyCommand constructor which saves the state. It is simple and should work. For a more general undo/redo approach, have a look at the [memento pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memento_pattern).  You can probably combine it with your command based approach.

Answer (score 0):

Java already have support for undo/redo operations. Have a look a this [tutorial](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/Undomanager.htm).
You can extends AbstractUndoableEdit class to define the semantic of undo/redo operations on your objects.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out this Swing feature, but it seems this only focuses on the presentation. I want to undo/redo it on my model!

Answer (score 0):

It's better to have a Backup of the old object in side your comand method.
I already used this type of approach .